# How does draw method of SurfaceView work?

Tags: android, surfaceview

Could anyone explain me how does `SurfaceView.draw(Canvas)` actually work? (and what it actually does).

For example I draw a rectangle on canvas and try to 'post' it on my SurfaceView.

```
canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100, p);
draw(canvas);
```

and nothing happens. I am really new in `SurfaceView`, I don't know how to use its method, but I thought that that one would just draw this rect.

Please be patient (I'm a beginner), and thanks for your time :).

Comment: see [LunarView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.java) ^F `lockCanvas`